# Add 1 to datediff result if time pass 14:30 or 2:30 PM

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Here is my SQL query which returns number of days by subtracting current date from specified date and returns exact as i need, but in addition i want to add 1 to result if current time passes 14:30 or 2:30.

My query

```
SELECT reservations.customerid,
       DateDiff("d",reservations.checkin_date,Now()) AS Due_nights
FROM reservations
```

Am using MS-Access DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be:

```
SELECT 
    reservations.customerid,
    DateDiff("d",reservations.checkin_date, Date()) 
        + Abs(DateDiff("s", #14:30#, Time()) > 0)AS Due_nights
FROM 
    reservations
```